# Show popup when click any record in odoo14

Tags: odoo-14

How to show popup when click any record of tree view in odoo14

I don't know do anything, help me please

Comment: Please provide more details and what you already tried to get a help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

judging from your question i am stating the answer.... go to the `views xml file` In `Xml` file remove `editable=bottom` it will show what you are searching for....

If i am wrong in understanding you then please add more details to your question